# Add line to the bottom of last cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have UiTableView. Cells on it by clicking change itself height. I need to add custom separator lines. I alwaays add to the top of cell. So all work fine, but last cell haven't seporator line on the bottom, and user cann't see the end of tableview. I try to add next code in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and then try use it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I create in the begin new UIImageView

```
@implementation MovieSessionsVC 
...
    UIImageView *seporatorView;
}
```

And this my code:

```
[seporatorView removeFromSuperview];
if (indexPath.row == self.sessions.count - 1) {
    seporatorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seporator.png"]];
    if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
        seporatorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 106, cell.width, 0.5);
    else
        seporatorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 63, cell.width, 0.5);
    [cell addSubview:seporatorView];
}
```

I use self.sessions.count for number of rows, and heoght of my cells is 64 and 107 when selected

So line appear and work fine, but when I pick up my tableview on maximum it is disappear

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using your CustomCell, and designing from XIB ?

Comment: Yes, custom cell add in storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isonly the last cell where you want to add something to, a line in your case, then it is probalby the easiest to draw the line on top of the footer view. You can create a `UIView` and assign that to the `tableFooterView` property of `UITableView`. That footer may just have a height of 1.0 and is filled with a colour. 
You can of course draw a line in `drawInRect` of that footerView. For doing so you will need to subclass `UIView`. But I think that some standard `UIView` with a background colour and a height of 1.0 would do.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the resize property of the separator image same as the image below

[image]

The separator image to sit to the bottom on any cell resize.. Make sure the cell resize property is all selected..